# How to handle asx pages inside tabs in one page

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have to program tabs in an aspx page. Each tab will contain a different aspx page.
I can do it with this jquery code and Div tags:

```
// In Default.aspx
<head runat="server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Styles/jquery-ui.css" />

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />

    <script>
        $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
        });
    </script>

    <script language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#tabs-1").load("First.aspx", {}, function (data) {
                // do something
            });

            $("#tabs-2").load("Second.aspx", {}, function (data) {
                // do something
            });

        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">First tab</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Second tab</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2">

        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

My problem is with postback of an aspx page contained in a tab. When First.aspx or Second.aspx postbacks, then Defautl.aspx just disapears and First.aspx or Second.asps takes control of screen.

One solution would be work with iframes instead of Div, but I had problem with iframes in the past and would prefer to avoid them.

Is there any way to work with tabs and each tab containing an aspx page?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you avoid full post backs and use Ajax post backs instead? Asp.net ajax might help you there. Otherwise you could just code the post back handler in your aspx pages to do their thing and then redirect back to your tab page, though that's a bit nasty!